# How to reduce DB querys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web-services

Lately I'm interesting in code performance and reducing DB query's as much as i can ,
first thing came up to mind is the well known youtube "302" bug and it let me think - is that a bug or just saving?

the reason i gave you "youtube" as example is because i'm working on something similar with the "views" thing , do i have to pull from the DB view number for each visitor ? or can i do something similar to youtube and update the views every few hours and (reducing? / saving?)

i'm going to deal massive page request , is there a technique that i can use ?

Comment: "is there a technique that i can use ?" - yes, caching.

Comment: You might find that writing the views to a flat text file for inclusion is more efficient. It depends on the needs, of course. Like storing the userdata for each view in a table that is processed via cron that evaluates and increments accordingly, writing the necessary files for each item.

Comment: Do you actually have a valid reason for considering performance optimisation? You know what [Knuth says...](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29)

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to reduce DB Querys further, you should use one of few caching technics.
This could be caching via memcache, using the cache component of your framework or use an frontendcache like varnish.

If you want to do a Videoportal, you will have much other Performance Issues which are related to your Streamingservers. The Time you put into the solving Frontend Issues are a waste, if you are not able to get you videostreaming performing well. But this to explain would get to much away from your Question.